# Locking the screen to landscape for only one activity

Tags: android, landscape, portrait

I have looked around SO and found how to lock my entire application to Landscape by editing the Manifest file. However, this is not what I want.

I want every activity to be locked portrait, except for one, which will be locked to landscape.

Comment: what's wrong with android:screenOrientation ? (reading SO is good, but reading documentation is even better)

Comment: I don't know what that is...Do I add that at the header of each XML file? And it permanently locks the orientation of that view?

Comment: You can't block a view in a certain orientation, all views will switch according to the activity(as the activity will recreate its layout). May I ask what are you trying to do? And what would that special view be?

Comment: My terminology wasn't correct, the activities are what I need to lock, not the views. The answer provided below is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your manifest file, find your Activity declaration and use the following:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you Rawkode.