# Stop App Screen Rotate to the Side

Tags: android

My app stops from working for some reason when the phone is rotated to the side and so the app does too. How can I avoid this, making it so it appears only vertically? Thanks a lot

Comment: Your app crashes because you have a bug. Your first response should *not* be to hide the error, but to find your bug and fix it.

Comment: It's a good question if the bug part is taken out.

Comment: I disagree; several duplicates should have come up in a search, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569052/locking-the-screen-to-landscape-for-only-one-activity or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730855/prevent-screen-rotation-android

Comment: I have no idea what the bug is. Why is it only if app screen is rotated? I use too many textfield, one after another and vertically it is shown ok, maybe horizontally can't fit to the screen and causes crush?

Comment: When configuration changes, the app starts over. But as mentioned above, you should fix the bug first that causes the crash

Comment: and I just tested it on the emulator and it orients fine, wtf :/

Comment: @darkchampionz Look at your logs. Any crash will have a stack trace. Find that trace, and see there what the error is. It will tell you exactly what line of code caused the error, and why.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your activities in android manifest :)

```
android:screenOrientation = "portrait">
```

Here is a full example:

```
<activity 
   android:name=".Activity.MainActivity" 
   android:label="@string/app_name" 
   android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your app's manifest file, set activity to be vertical... Its easy...

Comment: According to [Android Activity Element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), `vertical` is not a choice. Can you provide a reference?